# Is "Like Niobe, all tears" an apposition?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, shakespeare, appositives

From *Hamlet*, Act 1, Scene 2.

> and yet, within a month,—
>
> Let me not think on't,—Frailty, thy name is woman!—
>
> A little month; or ere those shoes were old
>
> With which she followed my poor father's body
>
> **Like Niobe, all tears**;—why she, even she,—
>
> O God! a beast that wants discourse of reason,
>
> Would have mourn'd longer,—married with mine uncle,
>
> My father's brother; but no more like my father
>
> Than I to Hercules:

I'm grammatically analyzing the phrase *Like Niobe, all tears*.

Are "Niobe" and "all tears" in [apposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apposition)?

> Apposition is a grammatical construction in which two elements,
> normally noun phrases, are placed side by side, with one element
> serving to identify the other in a different way. The two elements are
> said to be in apposition. One of the elements is called the
> appositive, although its identification requires consideration of how
> the elements are used in a sentence. <sub>Wikipedia</sub>

Comment: All comments have been [given a room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18129/discussion-on-question-by-ivanhoescott). Please use Chat for discussion, or add something to the relevant [Meta question](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/5290/why-do-people-think-this-questionlike-niobe-all-tears-is-proofreading). Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your first two answers are fine. "All tears" is a hyperbole, like "I am all ears".

Comment: I'm trying to grammatically analyze "all tears" in the above sentence by Hamlet.
I was well aware of an expression like "She was all tears".
However, in the above sentence, "all tears" appears without a subject or a be-verb.

Comment: "She was" are the elided words.  In context, it's an allusion to the Greek tragic heroine, Niobe, who wept unceasingly after the deaths of her fourteen children.

Comment: @ChrisSunami "She was all tears" does not seem to fit, because "all tears" is a part of the which-clause.

Comment: Note that the OP has substantially changed his question, to the point where this answer no longer makes sense.

Comment: As @Marthaª said, this answer is now so obsolete as to make no sense. You may wish to consider deleting it.

Answer (score 1):

As others have noted, your first two interpretations are correct.  For the third, the full phrase could best be understood as *She was all tears, like Niobe.*

Basically, *all tears* is a parenthetical explaining the allusion to Niobe.  Hamlet's mother followed her husband's body "like Niobe."  In what way was she like Niobe?  Like Niobe she was "all tears," consumed with grief --at least seemingly so.

You might best parse it as if there were an extra "like Niobe" in the middle.

*With which she followed my poor father's body like Niobe (like Niobe, she was all tears).*

Comment: I'm asking about the grammatical analysis, not about the meaning of the sentence. 
As I wrote in my comment, "all tears" is a part of the which-clause.
"Or ere those shoes were old with which she followed my poor father's body like Niobe, she was all tears." seems to be grammatically incorrect.

Comment: I understood your question.  My answer is that it is a parenthetical, referring to "like Niobe".  I will edit to elaborate. It's largely the same as your "apposition" hypothesis, but quite different from your original interpretation.

Comment: I think maybe with questions like this, the OP needs to define *exactly* what he means by any relevant technical terms. It's my understanding that "apposition" in the grammatical sense would be something along the lines of *"She was all tears - like **Niobe, the legendary grieving mother**"* (where the two nouns before/after the comma each identify the other, and no other syntactic requirements apply). OP here may have a considerably looser definition of "apposition".

Comment: Note that the OP has substantially changed the question, to the point where much of this answer no longer makes sense.

Comment: This is now an answer to a different question, not to the current one. You may wish to consider deleting it yourself.